# C# output differs between PowerShell and Windows Terminal PS

Tags: c#, powershell, interactive, .net-8.0, windows-terminal

Why in C#, when I invoke a script with PowerShell and capture the buffer, is the output completely different from running in Windows Terminal PS?

I'm supposed to be invoking the same application to run the command (PowerShell) from C#... as is running in Windows Terminal PS.

I'm running this C# application open with elevated privileges:

```
string command = "docker-compose -p wsdd-projects -f C:\Docker-Structure\init.yml up -d --build"

string policy = "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force";

string arguments = $"-NoProfile -Command \"{policy} ; '{command}'\"";

ProcessStartInfo processBuilder = new("powershell")
{
    Arguments = arguments,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    Verb = "runas",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};
```

Capture output with:

```cs
Process process = new() { StartInfo = processBuilder };

process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        if (showOutput) { terminal.AddToTerminal(e.Data); }
        output.AppendLine(e.Data);
    }
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        if (showOutput) { terminal.AddToTerminal(e.Data); }
        output.AppendLine(e.Data);
    }
};

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

await process.WaitForExitAsync();
```

I get this output from PS invoke from C#:

```
 reverse-proxy Pulled
 phpmyadmin Pulled
 faef57eae888 Pull complete
 989a1d6c052e Pull complete
 0705c9c2f22d Pull complete
 621478e043ce Pull complete
 98246dcca987 Pull complete
 bfed8c155cb6 Pull complete
 7a7c2e908867 Pull complete
 d176994b625c Pull complete
 2d8ace6a2716 Pull complete
 c70df516383c Pull complete
 15e1b44fe4c7 Pull complete
 65e50d44e95a Pull complete
 77f68910bc0a Pull complete
 605dd3a6e332 Pull complete
 99ce27188f07 Pull complete
 74d64e32c5d5 Pull complete
 ef5fc9928b9f Pull complete
 163f3256e112 Pull complete
 8a1e25ce7c4f Pull complete
 e78b137be355 Pull complete
 39fc875bd2b2 Pull complete
 035788421403 Pull complete
 87c3fb37cbf2 Pull complete
 c5cdd1ce752d Pull complete
 33952c599532 Pull complete
 80bad5b02d6c Pull complete
 b86cede81497 Pull complete
 876ba35ce95b Pull complete
 ac8fec215cc8 Pull complete
 7795496aa545 Pull complete
 4f4fb700ef54 Pull complete
```

Instead of this output in Terminal PS Windows:

```
[+] Running 33/33
 ✔ reverse-proxy 13 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                   14.3s
   ✔ 8a1e25ce7c4f Pull complete                                                      8.1s
   ✔ e78b137be355 Pull complete                                                      8.5s
   ✔ 39fc875bd2b2 Pull complete                                                      6.9s
   ✔ 035788421403 Pull complete                                                      7.6s
   ✔ 87c3fb37cbf2 Pull complete                                                      8.1s
   ✔ c5cdd1ce752d Pull complete                                                      8.6s
   ✔ 33952c599532 Pull complete                                                      8.7s
   ✔ 80bad5b02d6c Pull complete                                                      9.0s
   ✔ b86cede81497 Pull complete                                                      9.4s
   ✔ 876ba35ce95b Pull complete                                                      9.8s
   ✔ ac8fec215cc8 Pull complete                                                      9.6s
   ✔ 7795496aa545 Pull complete                                                      10.1s
   ✔ 4f4fb700ef54 Pull complete                                                      10.2s
 ✔ phpmyadmin 18 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                  18.4s
   ✔ faef57eae888 Pull complete                                                      2.3s
   ✔ 989a1d6c052e Pull complete                                                      0.5s
   ✔ 0705c9c2f22d Pull complete                                                      4.7s
   ✔ 621478e043ce Pull complete                                                      1.0s
   ✔ 98246dcca987 Pull complete                                                      3.0s
   ✔ bfed8c155cb6 Pull complete                                                      2.8s
   ✔ 7a7c2e908867 Pull complete                                                      3.5s
   ✔ d176994b625c Pull complete                                                      4.3s
   ✔ 2d8ace6a2716 Pull complete                                                      4.1s
   ✔ c70df516383c Pull complete                                                      5.1s
   ✔ 15e1b44fe4c7 Pull complete                                                      4.8s
   ✔ 65e50d44e95a Pull complete                                                      5.3s
   ✔ 77f68910bc0a Pull complete                                                      5.4s
   ✔ 605dd3a6e332 Pull complete                                                      5.9s
   ✔ 99ce27188f07 Pull complete                                                      6.1s
   ✔ 74d64e32c5d5 Pull complete                                                      6.5s
   ✔ ef5fc9928b9f Pull complete                                                      6.4s
```

Where is this line in my code? `[+] Running`

And the characters `✔` and `[⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]`?

Comment: I understand the utf-8 thing, but the characters [+] are simple characters...

Comment: I'm almost sure that docker has some type of output other than "OutputDataReceived" and "ErrorDataReceived" but I can't find anything related.

Comment: Looks like progress stream data (which the terminal is outputting as a progress bar and check marks)

Comment: @MikeShepard yes the output is the progress but it is show on lines with characters and some lines are hidden or prevent output on C# invoke PS...

Comment: I am lack C# knowledge, but from a PowerShell standpoint, I think you might be able to retain the display formating if you pipe your command to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string)

Comment: @iRon i would like to see a example of implementation code of Out-String, help me find one that fits with processBuilder

Comment: I guess that something like `string command = "docker-compose -p wsdd-projects -f C:\Docker-Structure\init.yml up -d --build | Out-String"` should already do the thing

Comment: let me check XD i need implement it with real time output stream per line

Comment: @iRon I have implemented "| Out-String -Stream" and it turns out that it shows the same thing, I think it is related to "how" the docker-compose command shows the output and I think it does so depending on the Windows terminal detected and the graphical properties... for Therefore, I think it is not a problem with the command or the docker composer, but with how PowerShell is invoked from C# and the properties of the invoked process.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all console apps will detect if the output is a terminal or a pipeline or a redirected file and stop outputting formatting in case the stdout is not a terminal. The formatting characters are just for beautified output and aren't useful for processing in scripts, therefore console apps will turn it off in a non-terminal output. If you run `docker-compose | where { $True }` in PowerShell or `docker-compose | cat` in a *nix terminal then the result will be the same as in your C# app

In docker it's the `--ansi` or `--no-ansi` option. Use `docker compose --ansi never` or `docker compose --no-ansi` depending on your docker version for consistent results. `docker compose --ansi always` also works but is only suitable for printing the output to an ANSI terminal because it may show hidden ANSI escape sequences which is unexpected in a text editor. It's the same effect as if you allocate a pseudo-tty in your C# and run `docker-compose` normally

Since you only want to process the output in C# then

Comment: i get unknown flag: --ansi

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover check your `docker-compose --help`, it's `--no-ansi` in some versions

Comment: i think that is a related bug with this: Options:
      --ansi string                Control when to print ANSI control
                                   characters ("never"|"always"|"auto")
                                   (default "auto")

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10013

Comment: This does not guarantee that it is the solution since I am supposed to have the process settings in C# so that it interprets the PS output as UTF-8 since there are other characters encoded to UTF-8

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover powershell output is always UTF-16 unless you set output encoding. But strings in .NET are always UTF-16. Anyway it's completely irrelevant because it's simply formatting characters that's entirely unnecessary when processing by non-humans, so why do you want those formatting Unicode characters in your C# string? Just process the normal `docker compose` output. Check the updated answer

Comment: although you may consider it unnecessary because a user has not executed the code (if they do it from a button); I do have a richtextbox viewer where I place all the results of the commands that are executed and I thought it would be correct or convenient to show it as it is seen in a PowerShell window. I have managed to capture the result by output event, managing to simulate it in a 90% of what happens visually in PowerShell but I just can't capture those characters or the Runing line N/N

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover in that case use `--ansi always` and parse the ANSI sequence yourself for formatting, or allocate a pseudo tty somehow, probably you'll need an external library. Printing progress in a pipeline doesn't make any sense, that's why you don't see docker printing `[⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]` in that case