# Receiving unknown flag from C# invoke powershell

Tags: c#, docker-compose, windows-terminal

in C# app i invoke powershell in a proccess to run this docker command: `docker-compose --progress tty ...` i get:

> unknown flag: --progress tty

Build command:

```
string appArgument = "docker-compose --progress tty -p wsdd-projects -f C:\docker-structure\init.yml up -d --build"

string policy = "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force";

arguments = $"-Command \"{policy} ; {appArgument}\"";
```

I am trying force a tty enviroment for docker command but it won't work.

However it works on a powershell terminal windows in same computer, [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78157816/c-sharp-output-differs-between-powershell-and-windows-terminal-ps)

It seems that I need to call not only the PowerShell process, but also make a window open hidden from the user to execute the command, apparently depending on whether it is a process or a Windows window it will have a specific behavior.

this is my build:

```
ProcessStartInfo processBuilder = new("powershell")
{
    Arguments = arguments,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    Verb = "runas",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};
```

***Update:***

Check versions and support from 2 enviroment caller:

[image]

Custom:

[image]

***Update 2:***

ok, ha ve detected that hiden termina is missing something that is requiered to handle tty mode... and i am get this message:

> powershell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force ; docker-compose
> ***--progress tty*** -p wsdd-projects -f C:\Docker-Structure\init.yml up -d --build" 
> ***Controlador no válido.***

and translation is:

> Controlador no válido = Invalid driver.

I have reached this point... no idea what this message is about...

Comment: Edit your question and add the actual C# and/or PowerShell code you're running. I suspect that the way you're invoking the process requires you to separate the arguments into a list in some way.

Comment: @JensV i have added the code related and command build.

Comment: Is there a reason you're running a PowerShell process which runs the Docker Compose executable rather than running the Docker Compose executable directly from C#?

Comment: @gunr2171 get the same output, and the command: docker-compose will invoke a cmd instance, I prefer to handle everything myself., Having powershell as an intermediary, if at some point I must manipulate environment variables or anything else, it can make it easier for me to concatenate other powershell commands with ";"

Comment: What's the output of `docker-compose --version`? I only see a `--progress` flag on my 2.24.6 version and it's not present in my 1.29.2 version. That may be the issue

Comment: In both places it is the same: Docker Compose version v2.24.5-desktop.1

Comment: So the flag is present when you run `docker-compose --help`? In either case, since compose v2 you should use `docker compose` i.e. without the dash.

Comment: yes, is present, for a moment I thought that the versions invoked from C# and PS Windows were different... but it turns out that they are the same... disregarding this... I can only speculate some dependency on the open winsows poweshell terminal window to be able to show capture tty mode

Comment: I bet tty mode is not supported when running a hidden powershell terminal. But they should have written a prettier error message...

Comment: yes i get now: Invalid driver. (Controlador no válido.) need solve it first to continue ... with tty mode